# Unable to call java methods from asp pages:

Tags: java, iis, asp-classic

i have the following problem with this simple asp page:

```
<%
Dim javaTestObj set javaTestObj = GetObject("java:test")

if javaTestObj.mstrLogin("pepe", "pepe") then

    Response.write("It Works!")

end if
%>
```

the Java class is the following:

```
public class test{
String pepe;

public test()
{
    pepe="pepepepe";
}

public boolean mstrLogin(String usname, String uspass)
{
    if((usname+uspass)==pepe)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}}
```

I have the compiled .class in every directory i've read it should be (C:\ClassPath\; C:\windows\java\trustedlib\ and in the same directory as the asp page) but i get no results =(

Any ideas of how it would work? I'm using IIS and the browser gives me this error:

Error type:
Microsoft VBScript compilation error (0x800A0401)
expected instruction end:
/login/pruebajava.asp, line 2, column 16
Dim javaTestObj set javaTestObj = GetObject
("java:test")
---------------^

Comment: Anyone that could help me? =(

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you just accidently omitted the colon (:) character, but the first line should read

```
Dim javaTestObj : set javaTestObj = GetObject("java:test")
```

because in classic ASP you are not allowed to declare and set a variable in the same statement

```
Dim myVariable    = "hello World"    '//Error! Not allowed.
Dim myOtherVar 
myOtherVar        = "hello World"    '//OK
Dim myVar : myVar = "Hello World"    '//OK
```